# php POST response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am making a POST to **another** php file that I want to render in the browser. the jquery post function does not redirect to another page. it expects the app-display.php file to return data to it. have a look at the code.

```
echo    '<div class="showcase_URL"><a class="purl" name="'.$row->num.'" href="#">PROJECT URL</a></div>';
```

what I have till now in javascript is:

```
$(".showcase_URL a").click(function() {
  //alert($(this).attr("name"));
    var number = $(this).attr("name");      
    $.post(
    "app-display.php", 
    {app: number}, 
    function(data){
        top.location.href = 'app-display.php';  
        });
});
```

what I have in app-display.php:

```
$query = 'SELECT num, title, thumb_url, url, type, cat, dated, details FROM app WHERE `num` = "$_POST[app]"';
```

but it is currently giving me a page without the contents of app-display.php. all the other fragments of the page are loading: header, footer etc.
the PHP Response (in Firebug) I am getting is the normal html of the page.

how should i do it?

Comment: Can you explain "so clearly, using jquery POST wont work, since it works through AJAX"?  I'm confused...you can post using jQuery and display the page however you want.  For example when you vote on SO you're posting and getting the vote total as a response and using it to update the page value.

Comment: @amit: the posted query is open to SQL injection. Hopefully it's illustrative and not representative of what you have in your actual code. Also, the current design isn't very clear. Names for all the files along with more of their contents (be complete, but concise; example code should be a minimal test case) should help clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use plain old `<form action="app-display.php">` That way you won't need to get data back.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `top.location.href` in your callback is the problem - that's a redirect.  `$.post()` is properly POSTing, and once that's complete it fires it's callback function, returning any results in the `data` parameter.  By redirecting in the callback, you're throwing all that away and making a straight GET request to app-display.php.

If you actually mean for this to be an AJAX call & not pass off to a new page, change the callback function to do something with the `data` parameter instead of redirecting.  Something like `function(data) { $('#some-div').html(data); }` should dump the response into some div.

Answer (score 0):

What else do you have in your PHP page except the line you've show that just defines a variable. Does it work if you just put some raw text in it, will it display? And after all I guess your query line is wrong, it should read `$query = 'SELECT num, title, thumb_url, url, type, cat, dated, details FROM app WHERE num = '.$_POST["app"];`